# Latex paragraph spacing and page Margins

Tags: latex

My latex file is:

```
    \title{\large\textbf{Optimizarea rela\c tiei dintre structur\u a \c si comportament \^in modelarea UML}}

    \author{
            Sorin Oltean \\
                    \textit{Universitatea Transilvania din Bra\c sov} \\
                    \small\textit{oltean.s@gmail.com, sorin.oltean@romtelecom.ro} \\
                    \small Tel.: 0752/314288
    }

    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \renewcommand\abstractname{\textit{\textbf{Abstract}}}

    \begin{abstract}
    Something..... text.........
    \end{abstract}\\\

    \textbf{Cuvinte cheie:}  \textit{sistem, structur\u a, comportament, UML}

    \section{Introducere}

    \paragraph{  } 
    Para11.............
    \paragraph{ } 
   Para2......
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{main}

    \end{document}
```

After para1, i wanna start a new paragraph, but between the paragraphs there is a blank line, how can i start the 2nd paragraph below the 1st one, without that blank space?
Also, how can i define the margins (top, down, left, right) of the document? There is too much space from the left, right, top and down, i wanna just 2cm space from the left and right, and 3cm from the top and down. Sorry for my bad english..
Also how can i specify the font name and size of the document?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't actually want what you think you want. The default settings highlight paragraph starts with indentation instead of vertical spacing, so the behavior you describe comes from using some package or document class option. (`\paragraph` is a sectioning command and has nothing to do with text paragraphs.)
Don't modify the page margins unless you have thorough knowledge of typography and know exactly what you are doing. The standard settings are fine (in contrast to the standard MS Word settings).
Also, don't change the font unless you know that you can use an expert font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) package. It allows full control over margins etc.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
```

The space between paragraphs can be set via `parskip`:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
```

However, `parskip` does not work for paragarphs introduced by `\paragraph`. But if your paragraphs do not need a caption (as I assume since you wrote `\paragraph{}`, it may be better to begin paragraphs just with a blank line:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
Here goes the first paragraph.

Here the second. With no space. Note that this paragraph was introduced with a blank line.

\paragraph{The third paragraph} This paragraph will have a small offset, since it is introduced explicitly with paragraph command.
```

Answer (score 10):

I see you make several mistakes that are typical for beginners:

- Don't use the standard classes for generic documents (`article`, `report`, `book`), they are too inflexible. Use the KOMA-Script classes (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook`) or the `memoir` class instead.
- Don't change the default settings until you have read books or articles about typography.
- In particular, the default page margins are OK, there is no need to change them. Margins of 2 cm would be way too narrow.
- When it comes to fonts, the answer depends on which engine you use: pdfTeX-based documents require specially-crafted packages, whereas modern engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX) can access system fonts. Like before, don't switch fonts light-heartedly. Only very few fonts of high quality are available to normal users. In particular, never use Arial or Times New Roman. On Mac OS X, you could use Hoefler Text, on Windows Cambria, for example.
- Don't include formatting commands in token lists that are intended for plain strings like `\title` or `\abstractname`; use the formatting commands that your document class provides.
- `\paragraph` is a sectioning commands that creates a heading; use blank lines to separate simple text paragraphs.
- Load the `inputenc` package (only necessary in the case of pdfTeX) so that you can enter non-ASCII characters directly.
- The `\documentclass` command must come first.
- Don't use the `geometry` package unless you have very specific and unavoidable requirements.
- Avoid the `parskip` package; modern document classes already include its functionality; and normally, paragraphs should be marked by indents, not by vertical space, so no changes to the default are required.
- Never use the `fullpage` package, it's completely outdated.
- Like the others said, start by reading some introductory material about LaTeX like the [Short Introduction](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/).
- Read the document [Obsolete packages and commands](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/).

Comment: Oh, wow! I need to set a good day to read and follow up on all the tips you gave on your post! Thanks for that  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) as a good reference to start with. Familarize yourself with the way documents are prepared for LaTeX.

1) There is no need to use `\paragraph{}`, just an empty line between paragraphs is enough. This will create a visible vertical space between paragraphs (that's why you wanted different paragraphs, right?). If you are bothered by the default indention for the new paragraph have a look at the documentation for `\noindent` or `\parskip`.

2) If you really have to start tweaking the page layout (i.e. your university/journal/employer doesn't already provide an accepted class or style) have a look at the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) package.

3) There should be some fonts available in your installation already (`beton`, `helvet`, `palatino`?), and these can be loaded as packages. It really depends on what exactly you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

For paragraphs, try putting your text inside the {} so that you have
\paragraph{ 
    Para11.............
}

But normally I think you can just put two lines between each paragraph and not bother with \paragraph{}. Otherwise, you can change the parskip value. Wikibooks shows how but I'm not allowed to post a 2nd link. It's in the Document Structure part of the Latex wikibook.

You can use the geometry package to specify your margins:

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm}

[Documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

For less margins I recommend using `fullpage`, i.e.

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
```

see [fullpage documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/fullpage.pdf) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Use the geometry package to change the margins of the document

```
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the space between the paragraphs can be configured with the package:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

Documentation in CTAN is [here](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=parskip). I haven't really tested it though.

For the margins you could do it manually with , the esaiest way is to do it the following package:

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

You can check documentation [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry).